# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError and Watir::Wait::TimeoutError:

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

I am facing  `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError and Watir::Wait::TimeoutError`

I have a snippet to click a device name on a overlay and click on the save button. The issue is this piece of code is working good in IE but in FF I am facing this issue.

Step 1: Clicking a required device name. Below is the HTML.

```
<div class="xwtObjectSelectorListTextAligned" tabindex="0" dojoattachpoint="osItemTextNode" aria-label="DeviceName" style="margin-left: 23px; max-width: 198px;">
    DeviceName
</div>
@browser.div(:class=>'xwtObjectSelectorListTextAligned',:text=>"DeviceName").when_present(30).click
```

The issue here is in IE this click is happening good and the required device is selected. 
But in FF there is no error thrown at this statement, but the selection is not happening.

Step2: After selecting device we need to click on the OK button on the overlay. Below is the HTML for that part.

```
    <span id="domCallprocessors_applyButton" class="dijitReset dijitStretch xwt-TextButtonContents" aria-labelledby="domCallprocessors_applyButton_label" role="button" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" tabindex="0">

        <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span>
        <span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar"> … </span>
        <span id="domCallprocessors_applyButton_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline xwt-TextButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">

            OK

        </span>
    </span>


 @browser.span(:id=>'domCallprocessors_applyButton').when_present(30).click<br>
```

In  FF at this statement I am facing the below error.

```
 Watir::Wait::TimeoutError:
   timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:id=>"domCallprocessors_applyButton", :tag_name=>"span"} to become present<br>
```

Can any one suggest a work around for this issue.

Below are the version details.

```
selenium (0.2.11) 
selenium-webdriver (2.37.0) 
watir-webdriver (0.6.4) 
Firefox Version: 24.7.0
```

Comment: Without more information I have to assume that the click event in Firefox fires correctly and it is the site that is mis-behaving (at least relative to your expectations) in a way that does not make the element in step 2 visible. Are you able to reproduce the site's behavior by manually clicking on the element on the same machine in Firefox? It might also be worth while to dump the page HTML and CSS to see if perhaps the ID is different.